"MAX(CASE WHEN ... END)" expression how it works
Can you explain to me how the expression MAX(CASE WHEN ... END) works?
For example, I have this query:
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'doctor' THEN NAME ELSE NULL END) AS doctor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'professor' THEN NAME ELSE NULL END) AS professor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'singer' THEN NAME ELSE NULL END) AS singer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'actor' THEN NAME ELSE NULL END) AS actor
FROM (SELECT name,
             occupation,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY occupation
                                ORDER BY name) AS rowno
      FROM occupations) subtb
GROUP BY rowno
ORDER BY rowno;

There, I understand the part that starts after the first "FROM". This part gives



NAME
PROFESSION
ROWNO




Eve
Actor
1


Jennifer
Actor
2


Ketty
Actor
3


Samantha
Actor
4


Aamina
Doctor
1


Julia
Doctor
2


Priya
Doctor
3


Ashley
Professor
1


Belvet
Professor
2


Britney
Professor
3


Maria
Professor
4


Meera
Professor
5


Naomi
Professor
6


Priyanka
Professor
7


Christeen
Singer
1


Jane
Singer
2


Jenny
Singer
3


Kristeen
Singer
4



But, I don't know, how part with MAX(CASE WHEN) converts this table into the following table:



DOCTOR
PROFESSOR
SINGER
ACTOR




Aamina
Ashley
Christeen
Eve


Julia
Belvet
Jane
Jennifer


Priya
Britney
Jenny
Ketty


NULL
Maria
Kristeen
Samantha


NULL
Meera
NULL
NULL


NULL
Naomi
NULL
NULL


NULL
Priyanka
NULL
NULL



It seems to me that MAX it is clearly audible here, since, as far as I understand, the CASE WHEN can fully cope without MAX. But no, if you exclude the MAX from the request it doesn’t work
This is answer of https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem, and the correct result would look like this:



DOCTOR
PROFESSOR
SINGER
ACTOR




Aamina
Ashley
Christeen
Eve


Julia
Belvet
Jane
Jennifer


Priya
Britney
Jenny
Ketty


NULL
Maria
Kristeen
Samantha


NULL
Meera
NULL
NULL


NULL
Naomi
NULL
NULL


NULL
Priyanka
NULL
NULL




By numbering all rows per profession alphabetically by name and then grouping by that number, you get no more than one row per profession in a group. For rowno 1 you'll get



NAME
PREOFESSION
ROWNO




Eve
Actor
1


Aamina
Doctor
1


Ashley
Professor
1


Christeen
Singer
1



Now, MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'doctor' THEN NAME ELSE NULL END) tries to find the doctor's name in the set. How is that done? The DBMS evaluates the CASE expression for each row, getting



NAME




null


Aamina


null


null



(provided the column is case-insensitive, otherwise we'd only get nulls, because 'doctor' <> 'Doctor'). The maximum value for this list, is 'Aamina' obviously, so MAX(CASE WHEN occupation = 'doctor' THEN NAME ELSE NULL END) returns that name.
We are aggregating the rowno 1 group to a single row here, so we need some aggregation function. In the query MAX is used, but we could just as well use MIN, as there is only one name per profession in a group. Some DBMS even feature the function ANY_VALUE to express, that you don't care which doctor's name you get (as there is just one), but carful ! there are also nulls in the data set, so you might get a null with such a function. This brings me to another point: In standard SQL you would not use CASE WHEN inside the aggregation function (which is called conditional aggregation, by the way), but use a filter clause, which makes this more readable and allows ANY_VALUE, too:
SELECT ANY_VALUE(name) FILTER (WHERE occupation = 'doctor') AS doctor,

SQL Server does not support the standard SQL filter clause yet, so we must use the CASE expression approach instead.
